# How to access populated document's fields in typescript/mongoose?

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, types, interface

I'm populating the **Customer** model and transform it with helper class. But I cannot access populated field's subfields.

**Order Model**

```
const orderSchema = new Schema<IOrder>({
  customerID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Customer",
    required: true,
  }
}

export const OrderModel = model<IOrder, IOrderModel>("Order", orderSchema);
```

**Order interfaces**

```
export interface IOrder{
  _id?: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  customerID: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
}

export interface IOrderModel extends Model<IOrder> {
}
```

**Order Helper**

```
export class OrderHelper {
  private customer: Schema.Types.ObjectId;

  constructor(model: IOrder) {
    this.customer = model.customerID;
  }
}
```

**Order Service**

```
class OrderService {
  private readonly orderRepository: OrderRepository;

  constructor() {
    this.orderRepository = new OrderRepository();
  }

  public async getProducts(request: Request) {
    const products = await this.orderRepository.findOrders(request.body);
    const data: ProductsHelper[] = [];
    for (let key in products) data.push(new ProductsHelper(products[key]));
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Order Repository**

```
export class OrderRepository {
  constructor() {
  }

public async findOrders(body: Partial<IOrder>) {
  const orders = await OrderModel.find(body)
    .populate({
      path: "customerID",
      select: ["customerCode", "citizenship", "passportSerial"],
    }).lean();
  return orders;
}
}
```

For example, I want to access Customer's customerCode field. But it gives me TypeError that there is no field of customerCode. How can I solve this problem? Is it related with interfaces/types or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare customer's type in order interface and helper. Then you will be able to access its (given interface's) fields.